# JSP Query.getResult().getNodes() Time Consuming

Tags: jsp, iterator, aem

I am running a query that returns 32k results and I am getting trying to iterate over those results via the Iterator returned by:

```
Iterator<Node> itr =  query.getResult().getNodes();
```

This method is rather time consuming; however, with a large number of results so my question is "Is there a better/faster way of iterating over these results?"

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can suggest is to increase limit of results for query. The default value is 50.
Iterator has some kind of lazy loading and it works in next way:

- You execute query and the default limit is 50.
- After iterator comes to 50th entry, query will be executed with limit 100 (or so) and offset 50.
- And so on.

So if you set limit before execution (`query.setLimit(someNumber)`) to some high number, iterator will fetch more (or all) nodes with first query. This will improve performance in your case.

Comment: There is only a setHitsPerPage()  function.  I tried this with 100,000 as the limit and there was no speed increase.

Comment: @user3916570 ok, I am talking about javax.jcr.query.Query, and you are using  com.day.cq.search.Query, am I right?

Comment: Correct, com.day.cq.search.Query

Comment: @user3916570 as I understand, you are using QueryBuilder to create queries. Nut sure if it's possible to optimize it and queries it creates. You can try to write query yourself, set the limit and test if javax.jcr.query.Query is faster.